# Pass self reference to contained object's function

Tags: reference, rust, borrowing

I'm trying to grok Rust's ownership model. I'm trying to pass a reference to a containing object when calling a function on a struct.

Here's my struct:

```
pub struct Player {}

impl Player {
    pub fn receive(self, app: &App) {

    }
}
```

As you can see, `receive` expects a reference to an `App` object.

```
pub struct App {
    pub player: Player,
}

impl App {
    pub fn sender(self) {
        // how to call player.test() and pass self as a reference?
        self.player.receive(&self);
    }
}
```

The above code gives me "use of partially moved value: `self`". Which makes sense, because `App` has move semantics so the value was moved into the `sender` function when it was called.

If I change it so that `sender` takes a reference to `self` instead, I get "cannot move out of borrowed content", which also sort of makes sense because we've borrowed the reference to `self` when we went into the `sender` function.

So what do I do? I understand why I can't store a reference to `App` inside `Player`, since that would lead to a doubly-linked structure. But I should be able to borrow a reference and perform operations on it, no?

I couldn't find an answer in the official tutorial.

I solved it by passing `self` as a reference in `receive`. But what if I want `app` to be mutable in `receive`? I can't pass `self` as mutable in `sender` because I'm also borrowing `player` as mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because `App` has move semantics so the value was moved into the `sender` function when it was called.

It's true that it was moved into `sender`, but that's not what this message is about. Because `Player::receive` takes `self` by value, you actually had to decompose `app` and move `player` out of it to be able to call `receive`. At that point in time, `app` is now half-formed; it has no valid value for `player`! If `receive` tried to access `app.player`, it would be using invalid memory.

> "cannot move out of borrowed content" [...] because we've borrowed the reference to `self` when we went into the `sender` function.

Right, which ties into above. Because we are borrowing an `App`, we cannot move `player` out of it, leaving the `App` in a invalid state.

> I should be able to borrow a reference and perform operations on it, no?

And you can, so long as the thing you are taking a reference to is completely formed at that point. There were also two hints in the above exposition:

1. > If `receive` tried to access `app.player`

   If you don't access `app.player` in `receive`, restructure your code to pass the other components of `App` instead of the entire container. Maybe you have some `GameState` that is really what you want to pass.
2. > leaving the `App` in a invalid state

   You can use something like [`mem::replace`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to put in a *different* `Player` into `app`. Then it's still completely (but differently) formed and can have a reference to it taken again.

Of course, the more practical solution is to change to accept references (`&self`).

> But what if I want `app` to be mutable in `receive`?

Yup! You'd get "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time". The solutions are actually basically the same, however! Decompose your `App` into smaller, non-overlapping pieces or disassociate `player` from `self` before calling the method.

Answer (score 7):

One way to follow [Shepmaster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36940054/155423)

> disassociate `player` from `self` before calling the method.

Is to put the `player` in an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/index.html):

```
impl App {
    pub fn sender(&mut self) {
        let mut player = self.player.take();
        player.receive(&mut self);
        self.player = Some(player);
    }
}
```

One last resource is to use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).